# CSS Animations - How to make it stay there after animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I got CSS Animations working on a logo. I make the image slide down from top to bottom, just once. How do I make the image stay where it went to after the animation stops?

Comment: have you got a link to the site, a jsfiddle, or some example code?

Comment: Well a slightly different approach may be needed. Anyway, good luck with it.

Comment: Can you make you jsFiddle example a working example?

Comment: Here is a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QeLVe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/4TcSK/5/

Jquery example for full browser support

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/GyYvz/

```
$('img').animate({ marginTop: '250px', opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I need it to go from top: 0 to top: 150 and stay at top: 150; after the animation compltes. This one (like my own example), jumps back up about 50 pixels. This is my problem I can't seem to get around.

Comment: This works perfectly on safari and chrome. It stops at the end of the last final frame http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-animation-fill-mode

Comment: Thank you very much @Vector i appreciate your help, I got it to work. I just refreshed the page a few times and it was all good.

Comment: Glad to help. I've also added another solution to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `animation-iteration-count: 1` to make it only play once, then complete instead of loop infinitely.

Comment: I have iteration-count: 1, but I do not understand the rest. Complete? How do I make it "complete"? Sorry I don't quite understand.